# Disconnect Salesforce before disconnecting the associated email address

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to disconnect one of my email addresses (a corporate address) from my personal Trailhead account.

a) From https://trailblazer.me/settings?lang=en_US and then...

b) From section "EMAIL ACCOUNTS *Manage your connected email accounts*", when clicking the button "**Disconnect**" next to the corp. email address I want to disconnect, Salesforce shows me this red message:

[image]

I have disconnected any Salesforce Account and I have even tried to perform the disconnection of the email address from a different laptop but I am getting the same above mentioned red message again.

How can I get over this red message and effectively disconnect the corporate address? Should I perhaps wait 24 hours?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Since this looks like a bug (the button "Disconnect" not working) I have logged a Case on https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help . I will share the solution here as soon as I get an answer from Salesforce Support Team

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Salesforce Team which has resolved the issue:

> Thanks for getting in touch with the Trailhead help team.
>
> You have two salesforce orgs connected to the trailhead. Please check
> any of the salesforce org use the email id which you are trying to
> disconnect. If yes, please disconnect that org before you try to
> remove the email id.

Comment: Interesting discovered "bug": integrity between the connected org and the Trailhead connected Org record /email address which is not updated when it is in the Org itself.